# Problems with Network Transform Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-unet

Currently I am having issues with my `Network Transform` component which is attached to my player prefab in my game. For some reason even though these are the correct settings for syncing rotation on the y axis when my player rotates on the y axis I can only see it on the local client and not on any of the other builds. (it is not being networked)

These are the settings on my `Network Transform` component:

[image: :]

If anything is unclear or any additional information is required to solve this problem please leave a comment and I will be quick to answer.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but does your game object have a rigidbody 2D? Does the rotation work if you set sync mode to SyncTransform?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to sync position/rotation of the non-player object across your network then, before performing position/rotation you have to assigned that **non-player object authority to your player**. 
For details you can check my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107855/unity3d-trying-to-send-command-for-object-without-authority/42689614#42689614)